# altering per-mode for a single siunitx-equation

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

I am using `siunitx` in "per-mode=symbol", and that is working very well. However now I have run into an isolated case, where I need the "per"-symbol to be `^{-1}`. Here is a MWE showing what I desire:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\noindent A speed of $v=\SI{888}{\meter\per\second}$, this is fine. \\
\noindent A lifetime of $\Gamma=\SI{888}{\per\second}$, not OK. It should be 888 s$^{-1}$.

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to define for a single "instance" that it should not use `per-mode=symbol`?

Comment: Do you mean for all `\per\second` cases or just this specific one given?

Comment: Just this specific one.

Comment: Perhaps `$\Gamma=\SI[per-mode=reciprocal]{888}{\per\second}$`?

Comment: You could also write it literally as `$\Gamma = \SI{888}{s^{-1}}$` (or `{\second^{-1}}`) but Paulo Cereda's/Joseph Wright's form is preferred.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `siunitx` commands all take a first optional argument to apply settings locally. Thus you want

```
$\Gamma=\SI[per-mode=reciprocal]{888}{\per\second}$
```

here.